# TFS/VSTS User Story Tasks to have Start/End Date automatically set based on Sprint dates

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, sprint, scrumboard

For my project in VSTS, I have the SCRUM Sprint with the Start and End dates set. I have created the user stories and tasks under each user story and have arranged the tasks according to the priority and also arranged the User Stories according to priority.

I want to know if there is some means in VSTS/VSO/TFS or a free tool in which I can connect to VSTS/VSO/TFS and import the Sprint and I can see the User Stories and Tasks with the tasks pick up start and end dates automatically based on the Initial Estimated hours for each task and Start/End Date of the Sprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Start and End date doesn't support to set from TFS web page. The Start and Finish Date fields are set in Microsoft Project and then synchronize that plan with tasks that are stored in TFS.

In the Miscrosoft Project, it has the Auto scheduled feature to set Start and End date, but it is based on Duration field in Project. And you want to use Original Estimate field in TFS to generate the date, so first you need to change the Project and TFS Mappings.

1. [Download the Mapping file using command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/upload-or-download-the-microsoft-project-mapping-file#to-change-how-work-item-fields-are-mapped-to-project).
2. Open the Mapping file and edit the OriginalEstimate field to map with Duration:

Code:

```
<Mapping WorkItemTrackingFieldReferenceName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" ProjectField="pjTaskDuration" ProjectUnits="pjHour" IfSummaryRefreshOnly="true" />
```

3. Save and upload this file using TFSFieldMapping command.
4. Open a Miscrosoft Project file and [connect to your Team Project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects#connect-from-microsoft-excel-or-project), export your workitems and set the Duration(Original Estimate) for them.
   [image]